# json to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is my json file input.

```
{"Report":{"id":101,"type":"typeA","Replist":[{"rptid":"r001","subrpt":{"subid":74,"subname":"name1","subval":113},"RelsubList":[{"Relid":8,"Relsubdetails":{"Rel_subname":"name8","Rel_Subval":65}},{"Relid":5,"Relsubdetails":{"Rel_subname":"name5","Rel_Subval":40}}],"fldA":30,"fldB":23}]}}
...
```

I am writing python program to convert the input into the below format in my dictionary.
I am new to python.

Expected output:

```
out: {"id": "101", "type": "typeA", "rptid": "r001", "subrpt_subid": "74", "subrpt_subname": "name1", "subrpt_subval":"113","Relid":"8","Rel_subname":"name8","Rel_Subval":"65","Relid":"5","Rel_subname":"name5","Rel_Subval":"40","fldA":"30","fldB":"23"
```

I used the following logic to convert the output till subrpt.

Current output:
out: {'id': '101', 'type': 'typeA', 'rptid': 'r001', 'subrpt_subid': '74', 'subrpt_subname': 'name1', 'subrpt_subval': '113'}

But I am struggling to get the logic of RelsubList(it looks like it has both list and dictionary[{}] ).
please help me to get the logic for the same.

```
import json
list1 = []
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
 
data_file = "samp1.json"
file = open(data_file)
for line in file:
    json_line = json.loads(line)
    json_line = json_line["Report"]
    dict1["id"]=str(json_line["id"])
    dict1["type"] = str(json_line["type"])
    json_line = json_line["Replist"]
    dict1["rptid"]= str(json_line[0]["rptid"])
    dict1["subrpt_subid"] = str(json_line[0]["subrpt"]["subid"])
    dict1["subrpt_subname"] = str(json_line[0]["subrpt"]["subname"])
    dict1["subrpt_subval"] = str(json_line[0]["subrpt"]["subval"])
    print("out:", dict1)
```

Comment: Your "Expected output" has duplicate keys (`Relid`, `Rel_subname` and `Rel_subvalue`), which isn't possible in a `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your logic is confusing to me, i.e.  why are you doing json.loads(line) in every loop?

Anyway, the following should get you the logic for RealsubList:

```
import json

f = open("data.json")

data = json.load(f)

 
for line in data:
    relsublist = data["Report"]["Replist"][0]["RelsubList"]
    
print(relsublist)
```

Results in:

```
[{'Relid': 8, 'Relsubdetails': {'Rel_subname': 'name8', 'Rel_Subval': 65}}, {'Relid': 5, 'Relsubdetails': {'Rel_subname': 'name5', 'Rel_Subval': 40}}]
```

The reason for the [0] index after ["Replist"] is Replist contains an array of nested dictionaries, so you need to call it out by index.  In this case its only a single array, so it would be 0